# there is a need adaptive version of the carousel

Tags: javascript, carousel

Carousel looks good on mobile screens , but it would be something she would look dignified and medium-sized screens. How is it possible to make out of this carousel adaptive? I would be very grateful for the help.

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <style>
div[data-role="carousel"] {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #beb;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div[data-role="carousel"] .fa-arrow-left,
div[data-role="carousel"] .fa-arrow-right {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #aaa;
    height: 30px;
    left: 5px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 60px;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100;
}
div[data-role="carousel"] .fa-arrow-right {
    left: auto;
    right: 5px;
}
div[data-role="carousel"] ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0 0 0 35px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: justify;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* scepll animation */
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 1s ease-in-out 0s;
       -moz-transition: margin-left 1s ease-in-out 0s;
        -ms-transition: margin-left 1s ease-in-out 0s;
         -o-transition: margin-left 1s ease-in-out 0s;
            transition: margin-left 1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
div[data-role="carousel"] ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px;
    width: 200px;
}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div[data-role="carousel"]')).forEach(function(carousel) {
        var list = carousel.querySelector('ul')
        var pages = list.querySelectorAll('li').length;
        var current = 0;
        var toLeft = carousel.querySelector('.fa-arrow-left');
        var toRight = carousel.querySelector('.fa-arrow-right');

        list.style.width = (pages * 230) + 'px'; // li.width + li.margin-(left+right)

        // 230 + 35, 35 = (300[carousel.width] - 230[li.width]) / 2[both side]
        var offset = 230;// start offset = 35, see CSS div[data-role="carousel"] ul
        toLeft.addEventListener('touchend', moveLeft);
        toLeft.addEventListener('click', moveLeft);
        toRight.addEventListener('touchend', moveRight);
        toRight.addEventListener('click', moveRight);

        function moveLeft() {
            if (current <= 0) {
                current = 0;
                return;
            }
            current--;
            list.style.marginLeft = (35 - offset * current) + 'px';
        }

        function moveRight() {
            if (current >= pages - 1) {
                current = pages;
                return;
            }
            current++;
            list.style.marginLeft = (35 - offset * current) + 'px';
        }
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="carousel">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
        <div class="gutter"></div>
        <div class="gutter gutter-right"></div>
        <ul>
            <li>(1)
                <p>
                    Phasellus porttitor ex nibh, bibendum dictum augue sollicitudin a.
                    Curabitur vel lectus mi. Sed sit amet urna lectus. Morbi nibh nunc,
                    gravida a ultrices in, tincidunt cursus ipsum. Phasellus nec justo ipsum.
                    Sed cursus justo et ullamcorper porttitor. Fusce fermentum sapien purus.
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>(2)
                <p>
                    Donec bibendum egestas elit, ut sollicitudin lacus bibendum vitae.
                    Etiam hendrerit nisl sed pulvinar laoreet. Curabitur id mi arcu.
                    Quisque accumsan placerat orci sit amet luctus. Nam odio risus,
                    tempus quis metus ac, pretium varius tortor. Duis ornare ante tellus,
                    fermentum gravida metus congue quis. Donec tempor, diam a consectetur
                    sollicitudin, velit libero maximus nibh, et congue elit tortor eget ex.
                    Integer eget arcu in sem mollis volutpat. Nunc congue convallis sem, a
                    luctus nulla suscipit accumsan. Integer porta, metus eget pretium semper,
                    felis magna maximus purus, ac sollicitudin lorem dolor a justo.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Curabitur ut dictum ipsum. Curabitur tincidunt viverra lectus ac elementum.
                    Praesent at mauris dignissim, accumsan ex ac, tincidunt lorem.
                    Nam malesuada erat orci, non semper quam tincidunt fermentum.
                    Aliquam et rhoncus massa. Integer condimentum ultrices augue sed
                    vulputate. Mauris iaculis nibh a nibh lobortis ultricies tristique
                    nec massa. Integer fermentum velit nisl, sit amet pretium tortor
                    dictum non. Aenean tincidunt efficitur enim. Nullam suscipit sapien
                    eros, non condimentum diam accumsan id. Suspendisse blandit ligula
                    dolor, eu luctus risus placerat vel.
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>(3)
                <p>
                    Phasellus porttitor ex nibh, bibendum dictum augue sollicitudin a.
                    Curabitur vel lectus mi. Sed sit amet urna lectus. Morbi nibh nunc,
                    gravida a ultrices in, tincidunt cursus ipsum. Phasellus nec justo ipsum.
                    Sed cursus justo et ullamcorper porttitor. Fusce fermentum sapien purus.
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>(4)
                <p>
                    Donec bibendum egestas elit, ut sollicitudin lacus bibendum vitae.
                    Etiam hendrerit nisl sed pulvinar laoreet. Curabitur id mi arcu.
                    Quisque accumsan placerat orci sit amet luctus. Nam odio risus,
                    tempus quis metus ac, pretium varius tortor. Duis ornare ante tellus,
                    fermentum gravida metus congue quis. Donec tempor, diam a consectetur
                    sollicitudin, velit libero maximus nibh, et congue elit tortor eget ex.
                    Integer eget arcu in sem mollis volutpat. Nunc congue convallis sem, a
                    luctus nulla suscipit accumsan. Integer porta, metus eget pretium semper,
                    felis magna maximus purus, ac sollicitudin lorem dolor a justo.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Curabitur ut dictum ipsum. Curabitur tincidunt viverra lectus ac elementum.
                    Praesent at mauris dignissim, accumsan ex ac, tincidunt lorem.
                    Nam malesuada erat orci, non semper quam tincidunt fermentum.
                    Aliquam et rhoncus massa. Integer condimentum ultrices augue sed
                    vulputate. Mauris iaculis nibh a nibh lobortis ultricies tristique
                    nec massa. Integer fermentum velit nisl, sit amet pretium tortor
                    dictum non. Aenean tincidunt efficitur enim. Nullam suscipit sapien
                    eros, non condimentum diam accumsan id. Suspendisse blandit ligula
                    dolor, eu luctus risus placerat vel.
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>(5)
                <p>
                    Donec bibendum egestas elit, ut sollicitudin lacus bibendum vitae.
                    Etiam hendrerit nisl sed pulvinar laoreet. Curabitur id mi arcu.
                    Quisque accumsan placerat orci sit amet luctus. Nam odio risus,
                    tempus quis metus ac, pretium varius tortor. Duis ornare ante tellus,
                    fermentum gravida metus congue quis. Donec tempor, diam a consectetur
                    sollicitudin, velit libero maximus nibh, et congue elit tortor eget ex.
                    Integer eget arcu in sem mollis volutpat. Nunc congue convallis sem, a
                    luctus nulla suscipit accumsan. Integer porta, metus eget pretium semper,
                    felis magna maximus purus, ac sollicitudin lorem dolor a justo.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Curabitur ut dictum ipsum. Curabitur tincidunt viverra lectus ac elementum.
                    Praesent at mauris dignissim, accumsan ex ac, tincidunt lorem.
                    Nam malesuada erat orci, non semper quam tincidunt fermentum.
                    Aliquam et rhoncus massa. Integer condimentum ultrices augue sed
                    vulputate. Mauris iaculis nibh a nibh lobortis ultricies tristique
                    nec massa. Integer fermentum velit nisl, sit amet pretium tortor
                    dictum non. Aenean tincidunt efficitur enim. Nullam suscipit sapien
                    eros, non condimentum diam accumsan id. Suspendisse blandit ligula
                    dolor, eu luctus risus placerat vel.
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are plenty of carousels that are 'responsive'. Google Carousel and pick. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Hello change your css.

```
 div[data-role="carousel"] {
 max-width: 100%; }
```

Your carousel will now be 100% of the viewport. You can control this further with media queries. Here is a JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gward90/k9vztr0v/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gward90/k9vztr0v/1/

Updated, also you can of course always change your column size based on media queries as well instead of them always being 200px wide.

Comment: I think that could be changed so that would js takes the input width 'li' and with it adjusted to the width of the 'ul', but my knowledge in java script is not enough

Comment: @Yuri Snisar I would recommend you make style and responsive changes with CSS and leave the functionality to Javascript there's no need to tackle responsiveness in this instance with JS. Did the fiddle work for you ?

Comment: @YuriSnisar thanks glad to help, could you hit the checkmark and upvote? So others can see this as a solution. Thanks